# Parse error at '[' : usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax

Tags: matlab, syntax-error

I am developing a small utility that calculates partial differential equation in `MATLAB`.
I am receiveing an error of invalid syntax:

`Parse error at '[' : usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax` in the function call, but I don't understand why:

Below the code I am using for the `main_routine.m`:

```
% pde operations ..

 % Explicit (nonstiff) integration
if(mf == 1)
    [t,u] = ode45(@pde_1, tout, u0, options);
end

%
% Implicit (sparse stiff) integration
if(mf == 2)
    S = jpattern_num;
    options = odeset(options, 'JPattern', S)
    [t,u] = ode15s(@pde_1, tout, u0, options);
end
```

Function call to `jpattern_num.m` where the error is:

```
function S = jpattern_num
global n

% Set independent, dependent variables for the calculation
% of the sparsity pattern
tbase = 0;
for i=1:n
    ybase(i) = 0.5;
end
ybase = ybase';
%
% Compute the corresponding derivative vector
ytbase = pde_1(tbase,ybase); 
fac[];   % <-- Error Here but don't know wy
thresh = 1e-16;
vectorized = 'on';
[Jac,fac] = numjac(@pde_1, tbase, ybase, ytbase, thresh, fac, vectorized);
%
% Replace nonzero elements by "1" (so as to create a "0-1" map of the 
% Jacobian matrix)
S = spones(sparse(Jac));
%
% Plot the map ….
```

**What I tried so far:**

1) I thought that it was just an array declaration problem but the error persists. I looked at the [official documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) to double check possible discrepancies but I could not find the error.

2) [This source](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/430107-i-have-a-code-but-it-keep-saying-invalid-expression-when-calling-a-function-or-indexing-a-variable) was very useful as the user had a similar project. 
I applied the same modification:

from

```
fac[];
```

I applied

```
fac();
```

But that didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

3) I dug more into the possible cause of the problem and came across [this source](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html), which always from official documentation. I applied what was advised but still the problem persists.

Please, if anyone had a similar problem, advise on how to sole this issue and guide to the right direction.

Comment: What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for reading the question. `fac` is a work array that is passed into and out of `numjac`.

Comment: Then I would expect something like `fac=[] ` for an empty array or a call of `zeros` to preallocate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line as it is now, is not creating an array. If you want to create an empty array, try

```
fac = [];
```

But the question is now, why passing an empty array to `numjac`? If the array will be created in the latter function, there is no need to pass it as an argument. In fact, if an array passed as an argument is modified in the function, Matlab creates a new array.

Comment: thanks for reading the question. that solved the problem. The reason why I am doing that way is because the `MATLAB` function `numjac` requires all the [necessary arguments](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/47171/versions/1/previews/A3_Distill/numjac.m/index.html) and thought that passing a pre-allocated arrays of initialized values would do the job.